# Socket not connecting after first connection failure

Tags: java, sockets, io

I don't understand why the following program doesn't work when the initial connect fails (I intentionally start the server socket after the first connect fails):

```
Socket client = new Socket();
while (true) {
    try {
        client.connect(address);
        break;
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

If I move the `client = new Socket();` inside the while loop, it works, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation that states that if an initial connect fails the socket is "broken" and has to be recycled.

Comment: I also can't find in the documentation, but as you found out, you cannot reuse the instance if it fails to connect. Just create a new Socket each time and don't forget to close the previous one that failed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reconnect a socket that has already failed to connect. You have to close it and try again with a new socket. The documentation you're looking for would be at the Berkeley Sockets API level, not Java,